# Pass selected value from Bootstrap dropdown to server.R in Shiny

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

I have my UI developed using an index.html with a bootstrap dropdown:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="shared/shiny.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="shared/shiny.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">                                            Selection<span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul id="selected" class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <pre id="selection" class="shiny-text-output"></pre>
      </div>
    </body>
```

I would like to use the selected value from the dropdown by passing it to the server.R and then print it out in the UI. The server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  # print selected option
  output$selection <- renderPrint({
    print(input$selected)
  })
})
```

I could do this using the basic Shiny widgets but I would like to try this out a different way. I could also use a more basic HTML select type:

```
<select name="selected">
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
```

and this I understand passes the selected value to the server.R using the `value=""`. But I am wondering how to do this using the bootstrap button classes. Do I need to bind a click event to the selected `li` and pass the selected text to server.R. If so how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the js code in a separate file called app.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#selected li a").on("click", function () {
      Shiny.onInputChange('selectedvalue', $(this).text());
     });
    });
```

On the server.R I used:

```
output$selection <- renderText({
    if (is.null(input$selectedvalue)) 
      return()
    input$selectedvalue
  })
```

Comment: Instead of the null check in server.R you could use

req(input$selectedvalue)

Answer (score 1):

Not full answer but I think it help you.

1) see `Shiny.onInputChange(`

2) You need to use it in js something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#selected').on('change', function () {
Shiny.onInputChange('selected',$(this).attr('value') );
})
})
```

3) Than you can use it on server side `observeEvent(input$selected,...`

Comment: Your answer really helped a great deal in solving the problem though I had to make some changes for it to work. The selector that worked in the js was `$("#selected li a")` and the event as `on("click",` with `$(this).text()`. On the server.R I did not need to use the `observeEvent`